# Does XSSFWorkbook,XSSFSheet work with office 2003 and office 2007

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using following lines to work with Office 2010 Excel file:

```
XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));

XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

Iterator<Row> rows = mySheet.rowIterator();
```

I was wondering if that will work with Office 2003 and Office 2007 (backward compatibility), or I will have to change the implementation, if it will not work, then how can i know the version of the excel file, and how will the implementation change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only works with office 2003, if [Microsofts compatibility pack](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3) is installed or you create an [HSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#user_api) output. Office 2007 should be no problem.

Comment: if this pack is not installed, then how to work with office 2003 ? and BTW how to find the Excel version with Apache POI ?

Comment: Version which wrote the file? or is installed?

Comment: wrote the file, i want to make a parsing code that should work with different versions of excel files.

Comment: The Excel 2007 file format (.xlsx) is very different from the pre-2007 (.xls) one.

Comment: It is usually, in the properties. You'd need to use something like WorkbookFactory though, as the file formats are very different, so you need to know / have something find you the format before you can get at the properties

Comment: guys, can we please edit the answer, and add one general answer to be used as reference for everybody.